# Windows 2008 R2 with RDP Services Remote Control fails intermittently with "Access is denied"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

While logged in as domain admin, I'm occasionally unable to use the remote control feature and get an "Access is denied" error message (or from procmon.exe by sysinternals "Remote Control: null")...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out...  It looks like [a known limitation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2484290) with Remote Control which does not support multi-monitor mode, and the error is not properly reported to procexp.exe (or even to RDP Services).  I have tested [unchecking this setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5hTA.png), and Remote Control works again.

It seems it was intermittent because users were sometimes remoting in from home / work where they had different display setups.